How Can I create cron job for laravel website on Hostinger?
I added this type of instruction but it was not working.

This is my output from hostinger:

Please give me the best solution for this type of cron job. I am using laravel 11 and its contains task scheduler in routes/console.php and I did not run that file automatically.

Are you sure that you put correct directory of the project & correct domain?

I don't know because it is my first time, and I also want to know how to run artisan command on Hostinger. I was created command in route/console.php-> Schedule::command('app:fetch-facebook-post')->everyMinute();

Could not open input file: /home/u291405664/domains/anardigitech.i/public_html/yogitech/artisan
I had getting this error from hostinger
